# In python insert one space after every 5th Character in each line of a text file

Tags: python-2.7

I am reading a text file in python(500 rows) and it seems like:

```
File Input:
0082335401
0094446049
01008544409
01037792084
01040763890
```

I wanted to ask that is it possible to insert one space after 5th Character in each line:

```
Desired Output:
00823 35401
00944 46049
01008 544409
01037 792084
01040 763890
```

I have tried below code

```
st = " ".join(st[i:i + 5] for i in range(0, len(st), 5))
```

but the below output was returned on executing it:

```
00823 35401 
0094 44604 9
010 08544 409
0 10377 92084 
0104 07638 90
```

I am a novice in Python. Any help would make a difference.

Comment: Are you sure this is Python 2.7? You seem to be using `range()` over `xrange()`.

Comment: Yes,I am using python 2.7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be two issues here - By running your provided code, you seem to be reading the file into one single string. It would be much preferable (in your case) to read the file in as a list of strings, like the following (assuming your input file is `input_data.txt`):

```
# Initialize a list for the data to be stored
data = []

# Iterate through your file to read the data
with open("input_data.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        # Use .rstrip() to get rid of the newline character at the end
        data.append(line.rstrip("\r\n"))
```

Then, to operate on the data you obtained in a list, you could use a list comprehension similar to the one you have tried to use.

```
# Assumes that data is the result from the above code
data = [i[:5] + " " + i[5:] if len(i) > 5 else i for i in data]
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks Jerry, but after implementing the content as you guided me when I try to print data it output is:

 []

Comment: @user8815323 It worked ok for me, but try putting both snippets in a single file and run it. Also make sure that your data file is named `input_data.txt`.

Comment: Also Here I am trying to convert a 11digit string into group of 5 and 6 digits.It's just that there are few 10 digit numbers in my file.

Comment: @user8815323 I'm not sure what you mean by your comments. Do you want the processed (split) data in a list?

Answer (score 0):

If your only requirement is to insert a space after the fifth character than you could use the following simple version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open("input_data") as data:
    for line in data.readlines():
        line = line.rstrip()
        if len(line) > 5:  
            print(line[0:5]+" "+line[5:])
        else:
            print(line)
```

If you don't mind if lines with less than five characters get a space at the end, you could even omit the if-else-statement and go with the print-function from the if-clause:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open("input_data") as data:
    for line in data.readlines():
        line = line.rstrip()
        print(line[0:5]+" "+line[5:])
```

Comment: Ups. Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: Indeed the question doesn't state clearly if it should be a space after the fourth or fifth character. Anyway the solution is easy enough to adjust.

Comment: Also, within the `else` clause, why would you bother slicing if you know you don't need to? And the `0` within the list slicings are redundant.

Comment: The question text states after every fifth character, while the question title states after every fourth characters. So it's a bit ambiguous.

Comment: I guess I see your reasoning, but both the code provided and the question body implies/states "after the 5th".